Merging three tables side by side
I know this is a weird request, but the company I'm at has a Java program built for an Excel macro that formats it this way. I need three tables: dibbs_nobid, dibbs_lost, and dibbs_won. There's a similar post about this with two tables, but I can't seem to add the last table to that one.
The three tables are as follows:



nsn_part_number
Reason




1
reason1


2
reason2






nsn_part_number
Reason




1
reason1


2
reason2






nsn_part_number
Reason




1
reason1


2
reason2



I want to achieve the following result:



nsn_part_number
Reason
nsn_part_number
reason
nsn_part_number
Reason




1
reason1
3
reason3
5
reason5


2
reason2
4
reason4
6
reason6



Below is the query I used to merge the two tables:
SELECT 
    dibbs_nobid.nsn_part_number,
    dibbs_nobid.reason,
    dibbs_lost.nsn_part_number,
    dibbs_lost.reason 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        dn.*, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY nsn_part_number) AS seqnum 
    FROM 
        dibbs_nobid dn
    ) dibbs_nobid
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
       dl.*, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY nsn_part_number) AS seqnum 
    FROM 
        dibbs_lost dl
    ) dibbs_lost
ON 
    dibbs_nobid.seqnum = dibbs_lost.seqnum;


Why do you have 3 tables with exactly the same information? The sample data seems unlikely in your real world. And does nsn_part_number mean the same in all three tables?  If so, then why are you changing the part number and reason when merging the tables?

Where are codes 3, 4, 5, and 6 coming from?

They all come from a bigger table, so 1 table is the part number and reason for an order status of no bid and so on. I just made a temp table and did the same process so got it thanks everyone.
